# openssl key result too small?

Tags: docker, openssl, apache2, rsa

I've got a docker that's perpetually in the `RESTARTING` status if an `entrypoint.sh` is run.

Checking `docker logs`, I see many repeats of these 2 chunks of error:

```
e is 65537 (0x010001)
140680312165760:error:28069065:UI routines:UI_set_result:result too small:../crypto/ui/ui_lib.c:765:You must type in 4 to 1023 characters
140680312165760:error:28069065:UI routines:UI_set_result:result too small:../crypto/ui/ui_lib.c:765:You must type in 4 to 1023 characters
140680312165760:error:0906906F:PEM routines:PEM_ASN1_write_bio:read key:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:330:
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
```

and

```
e is 65537 (0x010001)
unable to load Private Key
139751600240000:error:28069065:UI routines:UI_set_result:result too small:../crypto/ui/ui_lib.c:765:You must type in 4 to 1023 characters
139751600240000:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:536:
139751600240000:error:0906A065:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad decrypt:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:439:
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
```

My `entrypoint.sh` has this snippet regarding encryption:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:x -out /etc/apache2/ssl/pass.key 2048
openssl rsa -passin pass:x -in /etc/apache2/ssl/pass.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
cat /tmp/ssl-info.txt | openssl req -new -key /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in /etc/apache2/ssl/server.csr -signkey /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
```

This is a project I've taken over so I'm not fully familiar with this snippet, which is far more verbose than what I typically use to generate and use rsa keys, like in this [possibly related thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/366372/is-it-possible-to-generate-rsa-key-without-pass-phrase).

Can anyone please shed some insight into how this error can be solved?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I believe it's an issue with `pass:x`in line 1, x being only 1 character long.

`pass:gsahdg` etc should work(`gsahdg` is a random string).

Comment: Thanks! I was following https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-on-linux/ to generate a self-signed certificate for testing which was using `pass:x`.

Comment: @Larry Cai So, `gsahdg` is a random string we have to pass. Right? Do we need to save it somewhere? This random string?

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik I think this depends on your application. For me, I did not need to, AFAIK.